# Is there any way to create a gap in between the stacked vertical bars in Chart.JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

[Image of stacked vertical bars with space in between](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4CC5.png)

Is there any way to create a small gap between the stacked vertical bars in Chart.JS?
This is the example of the codepen: https://jsfiddle.net/5k32pn96/

There should be a small gap (10px) between the darker and lighter green

```
const data = {
    labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'],
  datasets: [
    {
    label: 'Retained',
    data: [62,68,74,80,66,84],
    backgroundColor: '#759BE4',
    order: 3,
    stack: 'stack1'
    },
    {
      label: 'Expired',
      data: [5,3,7,9,2,4],
      backgroundColor: '#307472',
      order: 3,
      borderRadius: 4,
      stack: 'stack1'
    }
  ]
}

const config = {
    type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: {
    scales: {
        x: {
        stacked: true
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true
      }
    }
  },
};

const reportOutput = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('chart_display'),
  config
);
```

Comment: A stacked bar chart is used "to show how one data series is made up of a number of smaller pieces", but putting a gap between those "smaller pieces" would automatically increase the value of the "data series" as a whole (the bar gets higher as it would be the sum of all pieces plus all the gaps).

Comment: After trying a lot of variants on your codepen and being puzzled that nothing worked I realised that it is using chart.js 2.4.0. In the future, please state the version if you're forced to use a particular old one, otherwise it is expected to be the latest.

Comment: Ah thank you, ive updated the code to chart.js v3 @kikon

Comment: In v3 you already have the [`borderWidth`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.7.1/charts/bar.html#borderwidth)  as an object allowing you to set different values for `top`, `bottom`, etc. ([fiddle fork](https://jsfiddle.net/b6hg02fd/)) - this has the disadvantage that it takes the border from the length of the bar; and you can also use [floating bars](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.7.1/samples/bar/floating.html), [fiddle fork](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqamrcuw/) this has the disadvantage that the gap is in value units, not pixels.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is a tricky, dirt workaround: add a fake dataset between those 2 and set the background color to the same of chart background (prolly white). And ofc hide fake dataset in legend and tooltips.

```
const data = {
labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'],
datasets: [
    {
        label: 'Retained',
        data: [62,68,74,80,66,84],
        backgroundColor: '#759BE4',
        order: 3,
        stack: 'stack1'
    },
    {
        label: 'placeholder',
        data: [1,1,1,1,1,1],//the more this is big, the more space between bars
        backgroundColor: 'white',//Same as background
        order: 3,
        stack: 'stack1'
    },
    {
      label: 'Expired',
      data: [5,3,7,9,2,4],
      backgroundColor: '#307472',
      order: 3,
      borderRadius: 4,
      stack: 'stack1'
    }
]
}

const config = {
type: 'bar',
data: data,
options: {
    scales: {
        x: {
            stacked: true
        },
        y: {
            stacked: true
        }
    },
    plugins : {
        legend: {
            labels: {
                filter: function(label) {
                    if (label.text === 'placeholder') return false;//label of fake dataset
                    else return true;
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            filter: function (tooltipItem) {
                const datasetIndex = tooltipItem.datasetIndex;

                if (datasetIndex === 1) { //index of fake dataset
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}};

const reportOutput = new Chart(
document.getElementById('chart_display'),
  config
);
```

Hope it helps.